# C#: XML To Type -LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to convert XML Elements to of type Person ?

**`Elements :`**

```
XElement persons = XElement.Parse(
               @"<persons>
                   <person>
                        <id>10001</id>     
                       <name> Daniel </name> 
                   </person>
                   <person>
                        <id>10002</id>     
                       <name>Marshal</name> 
                   </person>
                    <person>
                        <id>10003</id>     
                       <name>Leo</name> 
                   </person>
                 </persons>"
            );
```

**`Person Type:`**

```
class Person
    {
        int personID;
        string name;

        public int PersonID
        {
            get {return personID;}
            set {personID = value;}
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get {return name;}
            set {name = value;}
        }
    }
```

**`I tried (incomplete & not sure whether valid approach )`**

```
 Person[] Prns = from perns in persons.Nodes select new {perns};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var personList =
    from p in persons.Elements("person")
    select new Person
    {
        Name = p.Element("name").Value,
        PersonID = int.Parse(p.Element("id").Value)
    };
```

Comment: Fine.Thanks for spending your time.Working well.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use XML serialization, but using LINQ to XML is probably easier:

```
[XmlType("person")]
public class Person
{
    int personID;
    string name;

    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int PersonID
    {
        get { return personID; }
        set { personID = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}

…

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person[]), new XmlRootAttribute("persons"));
var result = (Person[])serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```